Why does Kotlin MultiPlatform Desktop project build failed due to AndroidManifest issues
Im investigating Kotlin Multiplatform project development in INTELIJ IDE.
When I employed the KMP Plugin new project wizard I only selected Desktop, not Android or iOS etc...
what I do not understand is that when i rebuild the project in InteliJ the build fails with this exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':composeApp:processDebugMainManifest' (type 'ProcessApplicationManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest' property 'mainManifest' specifies file '/DayOut/composeApp/src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.
    
    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
      2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/validation_problems.html#input_file_does_not_exist in the Gradle documentation.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 745ms

why is a desktop only project looking for an Android manifest file?
However I can run the desktopMain main.kt generated code and it works fine
package org.example.composeApp

import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application

fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        title = "DayOut",
    ) {
        App()
    }
}


Please post the contents of your build.gradle.kts file within your shared or composeApp folder.  You probably still have Android() or AndroidTarget content still floating around.
